# Backbone render function: Unexpected token ILLEGAL

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, underscore.js

I have the following error when trying to render a backbone.js template:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
```

From the following code, 2nd line, on the call to html:

```
render: function() {
        $(this.el).html(_.template(contactTemplate, {
            model: this.model.toJSON(),
        }));
        return this;
    }
```

I don't understand what the illegal character is or what is happening, any help would be much appreciated.

EDIT:
Thank you for your help, you were correct, my template was at fault, turns out I had:

```
<p><a href="#profile/<%=model.accountId%">View</a></p>
```

Instead of

```
<p><a href="#profile/<%=model.accountId%>">View</a></p>
```

The joy of coding :)

Comment: are you getting any result by `_.template(contactTemplate, { model: this.model.toJSON() });`. And try removing the extra `,` after `toJSON` call.

Comment: It might help if you post the template since you've now got two of essentially the same answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think Backbone must have driven you a little object literal crazy!

```
render: function() {
        $(this.el).html(_.template(contactTemplate, {
            model: this.model.toJSON(),
        }));
        return this;
    }
```

Would only work (I think) if your template had fields specified like `<%= model.field1 %>`.  Try this:

```
render: function() {
        $(this.el).html(_.template(contactTemplate, this.model.toJSON()));
        return this;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you get that error when you are trying to access an undefined field from your model. by looking at your code your template has to look like this when you try to get the json values:

```
<b> the value of field AAA is <%= model.AAA %> </b>
```

if you wan to avoid to use model just call:

```
 _.template(contactTemplate, this.model.toJSON() )
```

then you can do something like

```
<b> the value of field AAA is <%= AAA %> </b>
```

Comment: Correct that is what my template looks like, I rewrote it following what you have above and still the same error. Also tried both with an empty template (as in no values, just some html text) and still the same error